# No sound - pulseaudio - Ubuntu 20.04 (but sound with pulseaudio uninstalled)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 20.04

I recently upgraded from 14.04 all the way up to 20.04 (on a Dell Latitude E7470) and after resolving a few minor issues there is one with the sound and pulseaudio that is beyond me. I write more details below, but in short, I get audio when I uninstall pulseaudio and can control volumes with alsamixer. As soon as I install pulseaudio back, then the sound goes away. Has anyone encountered this before? Are there known solutions? I tried many of the solutions online, but those (1) didn't work and (2) it seemed to me were more related to no sound at all, even without pulseaudio. Any help will be very much appreciated!

1) Uninstalling pulseaudio `sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio` leaves me, I presume, with just ALSA running the show and I do get sound. It is not perfect and I cannot control volumes and select speakers easily. As soon as I install it back

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse_backup
```

and reboot then I have no sound. This is a snapshot [image] of the Settings-->Sound menu. When I type `pavucontrol`, in the Output Devices tab, I do see the Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI) detecting sound (the volume bar moves around as I play something on youtube), but no actual sound. Is it pulseaudio detecting the correct sound card? I tried all the Profiles in the Configuration tab in pavucontrol, but nothing. In Settings->Sound, I also cannot select or see other output devices. Running `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` returns

> Codec: Realtek ALC3235
>
> Codec: Intel Skylake HDMI

Is it a potential problem that this returns two entries? Pulseaudio does indicate it detects something with HDMI, should it be detecting the Realtek sound card instead? Appologies if these are really basic questions -- newbie here. The output of `lspci | grep Audio` is

> 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev
>   21)

and the output of `aplay -l` is

> **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3235 Analog [ALC3235 Analog]   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI
>   0 [HDMI 0]   Subdevices: 0/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH
>   [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI
>   2 [HDMI 2]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH
>   [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]   Subdevices: 1/1
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10:
>   HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

The device 0 is indeed the Realtek, but pulseaudio seems to preferentially detect the HDMI ones. Is this where the problem lies?

2) I tried many of the solutions I found online. There is a very popular one [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto), which involves adding

> options snd-hda-intel model=RIGHT_MODEL  to  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

or

> options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0  to  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
>
> blacklist snd_soc_skl                to  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

I tried this out of desperation, but none worked. I also tried several of the available options online for "RIGHT_MODEL", but none worked.  I'm not sure, but these solutions seemed related with no sound at all (even without pulseaudio), whereas I do get audio when pulseaudio is uninstalled.

3) The output of `uname -r` is

> 5.4.0-29-generic

I found some information on sound-related bugs online ([here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1869799) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061)) associated with the latest Linux kernels, but cannot tell whether that could be what's causing my problem.

Anyway, sorry for a long post, but I wanted to be comprehensive. If someone knows the solution, hopefully this can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: From which port do you get the sound when you do not use pulseaudio?

Comment: On alsamixer I can see Chip: ALC3235 . This is device 0 in aplay -l. Without pulseaudio the sound does go through the built-in speakers.

Comment: One more thing. Without pulseaudio, I control the volume just fine on alsamixer on the Master column. If the headphones are plugged in, controlling the volume on the Headphones column also works. When the sound comes from the speakers, controlling the volume on the Speakers column is also fine.

Comment: Same thing here with m-audio external card. Alsa sees it fine, not pulseaudio. Did you get it resolved ? I only managed to get it done using Jack and the jack-pulseuadio bridge

Comment: No, to this day I've kept pulseaudio uninstalled and controlled the volume on the command line with "alsamixer" . I absolutely require sound to join work conferences so I am glad this at least works -- not ideal of course: cannot control volume on the keyboard, it doesn't detect wireless phones on bluetooth, etc.

Can you provide more details on your workaround?